# Horizontal sort of paired entries

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

My VBA skills are basic. I would appreciate help with sorting numbers in a row but with moving their corresponding strings. For example, these rows:

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ Name1 ║ Number1 ║ Name2 ║ Number2 ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║ Joe   ║       5 ║ John  ║      10 ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

should become:

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ Name1 ║ Number1 ║ Name2 ║ Number2 ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║ John  ║      10 ║ Joe   ║       5 ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

The code I am trying to adjust is:

```
Sub hsort()
Dim lLast As Long, lLoop As Long
lLast = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For lLoop = 2 To lLast
range(cells(lLoop,4),cells(lLoop,23)).Sort key1:=Cells(lLoop, 5), order1:=xlDescending,key2:=Cells(lLoop, 4), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _False, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
Next
End Sub
```

which orders the strings first and then the numbers, rather than moving them together as wished.

Comment: If you want to get quick response and not get downvoted, it would be wise if you post what you tried.

Comment: You mean the code I already tried or something like a screenshot of my data?

Comment: Ideally both ... as it would help SO users to fix the exact issue rather than coding the entire thing.

Comment: You can't do this using normal and direct `Sort`. What i suggest is to re-arrange data in a temp sheet, sort and paste back the original location.

Comment: Using VBA, you can store the data in a `Dictionary` where **Name_n_** can be the `Key` and **Number_n_** can be the `Items`. Then you can sort the data and paste it on sheet.

Comment: @pnuts - Probably yes. Will try to find a simpler solution ... probably a non vba one cause I think I can use `Transpose` and Excel `Sort` features to do this.

Comment: It can be assumed that you have an even number of columns, yes? Since it's by pairs of two... I might have a quick solution.

Comment: it is even indeed. I need reordering from column 5 to column 24; therefore are 20 columns

Comment: Posted code below. As I detailed, it's up to you to change the ranges involved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy with a dictionary, but as @pnuts pointed out, it's a bit advanced. What we're going to do here is to invoke a dictionary, store your data there, transfer them to an array, bubble sort them in descending order, put them back into the dictionary, and print them out.

***Whew.*** Anyway, credits to [this site](http://www.xl-central.com/sort-a-dictionary-by-item.html) for the framework.

Anyway, code first.

```
'http://www.xl-central.com/sort-a-dictionary-by-item.html
Sub SortDictionaryByItem()

    'Set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime by using
    'Tools > References in the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11)

    'Declare the variables
    Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim Temp1 As Variant
    Dim Temp2 As Variant
    Dim Txt As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long, Iter As Long, Iter2 As Long, Iter3 As Long

    'Create an instance of the Dictionary
    Set Dict = New Dictionary

    'Set the comparison mode to perform a textual comparison
    Dict.CompareMode = TextCompare

    '''''''''''''''''BK201's Mod'''''''''''''''''

    'Get the last column of the row.
    LastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column 'Modify accordingly.
    'Add keys and items to the Dictionary
    For Iter = 1 To (LastCol - 1) Step 2
        Dict.Add Cells(1, Iter).Value, Cells(1, Iter + 1).Value
    Next Iter
    '''''''''''''''''BK201's Mod'''''''''''''''''

    'Allocate storage space for the dynamic array
    ReDim Arr(0 To Dict.Count - 1, 0 To 1)

    'Fill the array with the keys and items from the Dictionary
    For i = 0 To Dict.Count - 1
        Arr(i, 0) = Dict.Keys(i)
        Arr(i, 1) = Dict.Items(i)
    Next i

    'Sort the array using the bubble sort method
    For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
            If Arr(i, 1) < Arr(j, 1) Then
                Temp1 = Arr(j, 0)
                Temp2 = Arr(j, 1)
                Arr(j, 0) = Arr(i, 0)
                Arr(j, 1) = Arr(i, 1)
                Arr(i, 0) = Temp1
                Arr(i, 1) = Temp2
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'Clear the Dictionary
    Dict.RemoveAll

    'Add the sorted keys and items from the array back to the Dictionary
    For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)
        Dict.Add Key:=Arr(i, 0), Item:=Arr(i, 1)
    Next i

    '''''''''''''''''BK201's Mod'''''''''''''''''
    'Change Cells(2, Iter2) to Cells(1, Iter2) to overwrite.
    KeyIndex = 0
    For Iter2 = 1 To (LastCol - 1) Step 2
        Cells(2, Iter2).Value = Dict.Keys(KeyIndex)
        KeyIndex = KeyIndex + 1
    Next Iter2

    For Iter3 = 2 To LastCol Step 2
        Cells(2, Iter3).Value = Dict.Item(Cells(2, Iter3 - 1).Value)
    Next Iter3
    '''''''''''''''''BK201's Mod'''''''''''''''''

    Set Dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Screenshots:**

***Set-up:***

[image]

***Result after running code:***

[image]

Modify the ranges involved accordingly. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Based on your comments above, just changing `Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column` to `Range("A5").End(xlToRight).Column` should be enough. I did not bother overwriting so you can see it firsthand. Check near the end the comments for the change needed to overwrite. :)

Comment: Yes that's perfect, thank you! But there is only one thing I don't understand that I would like to ask to you. Why in the last iteration within the Dict.Item parentheses you put a cell rater than the value in the dictionary as done in the previous iteration?

Comment: Good eye on that. Basically, I assumed one thing here: that the names are unique. Otherwise, storing them as keys can cause an error. This is because no two keys can have the exact same name. Now, in the first of the last two iterations, I map out the sorted names first. These names are key values. In the second iteration, to be sure that only the corresponding "partner" value is returned to us, we use the names to access the value in the dictionary's key-value pairs. Does this make sense? :)

Comment: Basically, `Dict.Item(x)` returns the value from key `x`. Since we've already mapped out the keys (the names), all that's left is getting their respective values. So we iterate again over the cells, but then we refer to the adjacent cell to the left, which contains the name (key) and use it to extract its partner value. :) This is far safer than using a number index to get the items, which can cause unlimited grief any which way I look at it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Name1` is in A1, if you add temporarily a row between `Name1` and `John` with `=IF(ISEVEN(COLUMN()),A3,B3)` in it copied across to suit you should then achieve the order I think you want with a normal left to right sort and the temporary row can then be deleted. Build this in to VBA if you wish.

Comment: I think I should have explained better what I needed.

Comment: I have in the first row the headers from A1 to X1. the first 3 Columns must not be reordered; then I have 5000 lines of data that I have to order line by line. Horizontal sort does not work because it reorder all the cells selected while I need that if the value in column H is the bigger then columns G and H both move in the 1st position that in my case is columns D and E

Answer (score 0):

At the end this is the solution I adopted but is really Really slow! Does anyone have any suggestion to improve this code? Dictionary seemed to me a good solution but I don't know how to use it so I ask you if it is implementable in this situation.

```
Sub Reorder()

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
Dim i, c, j As Integer
i = 7

Do
j = 5
Do
Workbooks("Ownership Full v3.xlsx").Activate
Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 1)).Copy
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Activate
If Range("A2") = blank Then
Range("A2").Select
Else
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
ActiveSheet.Paste
j = j + 2
Workbooks("Ownership Full v3.xlsx").Activate
Loop While (j <= 23)

Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B2:B11").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B11")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        End With


j = 5
c = 2
Do
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Activate
Range(Cells(c, 1), Cells(c, 2)).Cut
Workbooks("Ownership Full v3.xlsx").Activate
Cells(i, j).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
c = c + 1
j = j + 2
Loop While (c <= 11)

i = i + 1

Loop While (Cells(i, 1) <> blank)

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```